# How can I show addition of two variables and also a text in TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I have two variables. I need to show these variables addition and also add some text in textView.

Example

val a
val b

The text i needed
"Addition is (a+b)"

Sorry if i've done any mistake, I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

```
val a =...
val b =...

val textView =...
```

In Kotlin you can use interpolation so

```
textView.text = "Addition is ($a+$b)"
```

the Android way of doing so is using the `strings.xml`

```
<string name="addition">Addition is (%1d+%2d)</string>
```

And then

```
textView.text = resources.getString(R.string.addition, a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int c=a+b;
     
    String textNeeded="Addition is "+c;

    textView.setText(textNeeded);
```